# Jmeter : I ran with live project with Thread 100 ramp- up 3000 ms and loop 1

Tags: jmeter

Please help my report is correct or not.  I put in 1000 thread ,rampup-3000 ms, loop =1 and In my script there are 13 sample recorded so total 13000 sample Run . According to report it takes 00:51:13 to complete execution.

My reports :

1. Summary Report : No of sample 13000, Std Deviation 24106 , Error : 14.45%, Through put time : 4.2/sec
2. Table report : No of sample 13000, Average 3309 , Deviation 24106
3. Graph Result :  No. of Sample :11121  Average 1559 Deviation 2691 Throughput 219.383/MIn

please help me to analyse above reports are acceptable or not. Error 14.45 % is acceptable or not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90yqH.jpg)

Comment: Tried to find out best result of response time. What will be the best  average response time if Thread =1000 Rampup= 3000 and loop= 1. I have to analyse and report client so please help to find out best response time with best combination of Thread, Rampup

Comment: I don't think you will find people here to write your report for your client... please have look here: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And search for basics on load analysis. What are you trying to achieve? What is it that you want to know? How would you measure what you are looking for. What is your context? Just throwing some numbers has no meaning. It only will get down voted.

Answer (score 1):

what type of samples do you have? What do you test and what you want to achieve?

Normally we consider only Error:0% as correct. It means, your application, server architecture or network can correctly handle all of request without faultiness.

Sometimes it is important to repeat the same test to observe average Response Time / Throughput.